# How to sort an ls-like file list?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix, shell

How do I sort by the last column a list which looks like this:

```
drwxr-sr-x   2 user     group           4096 2018-02-19 14:11:42  /something/project/somefile
drwxr-sr-x   2 user     group           4096 2018-02-19 00:14:50  /blah-blah/anything
-rw-r-----   1 someone  users           2188 2018-07-21 13:52:59  /aaa/222
drwxr-S---   2 someone  users           4096 2018-06-25 14:27:42  /bbb/333/anything/whatever
-rw-r-----   1 someone  users            715 2018-06-16 20:09:58  /xxx/aaa/666
```

*The list is in a file but not generated by `ls` so I cannot use ls's functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sort`:

```
sort -k8,8 <<EOF
drwxr-sr-x   2 user     group           4096 2018-02-19 14:11:42  /something/project/somefile
drwxr-sr-x   2 user     group           4096 2018-02-19 00:14:50  /blah-blah/anything
-rw-r-----   1 someone  users           2188 2018-07-21 13:52:59  /aaa/222
drwxr-S---   2 someone  users           4096 2018-06-25 14:27:42  /bbb/333/anything/whatever
-rw-r-----   1 someone  users            715 2018-06-16 20:09:58  /xxx/aaa/666
EOF
```

`-k` selects which field to sort on, `8,8` says to sort on data from field 8, to field 8.

You can use `-t` to define the field separator, though the default here is fine (non-blank to blank transition).

Output:

```
-rw-r-----   1 someone  users           2188 2018-07-21 13:52:59  /aaa/222
drwxr-S---   2 someone  users           4096 2018-06-25 14:27:42  /bbb/333/anything/whatever
drwxr-sr-x   2 user     group           4096 2018-02-19 00:14:50  /blah-blah/anything
drwxr-sr-x   2 user     group           4096 2018-02-19 14:11:42  /something/project/somefile
-rw-r-----   1 someone  users            715 2018-06-16 20:09:58  /xxx/aaa/666
```

---

To followup, you asked:

> My file containing the list also has N starting and M ending lines which are not in the column-like form shown above. Unfortunately the sorting messes them up. How can I exclude those lines and sort just the columned ones?

You'll need to know how many lines are *before* / *in* / *after* the block to be sorted, and you can substitute the values used below with variables. A simple pipeline like shown below can work well.

Content of `data.txt`:

```
Zline1
Zline2
drwxr-sr-x   2 user     group           4096 2018-02-19 14:11:42  /something/project/somefile
drwxr-sr-x   2 user     group           4096 2018-02-19 00:14:50  /blah-blah/anything
-rw-r-----   1 someone  users           2188 2018-07-21 13:52:59  /aaa/222
drwxr-S---   2 someone  users           4096 2018-06-25 14:27:42  /bbb/333/anything/whatever
-rw-r-----   1 someone  users            715 2018-06-16 20:09:58  /xxx/aaa/666
AlineN-1
AlineN
```

Pipeline:

```
(head -n 2; head -n 5 | sort -k8,8; cat) < data.txt
```

Output:

```
Zline1
Zline2
-rw-r-----   1 someone  users           2188 2018-07-21 13:52:59  /aaa/222
drwxr-S---   2 someone  users           4096 2018-06-25 14:27:42  /bbb/333/anything/whatever
drwxr-sr-x   2 user     group           4096 2018-02-19 00:14:50  /blah-blah/anything
drwxr-sr-x   2 user     group           4096 2018-02-19 14:11:42  /something/project/somefile
-rw-r-----   1 someone  users            715 2018-06-16 20:09:58  /xxx/aaa/666
AlineN-1
AlineN
```

Comment: Thanks! May I also ask: my file containing the list also has N starting and M ending lines which are not in the column-like form showne above. Unfortunately the sorting messes them up. How can I exclude those lines and sort just the columned ones?

Comment: See my update :-)

Comment: Thank you! Actually I found that `(head -n <N>; tail -n +<N+1> | head -n -<M> | sort -s -k8,8; tail -n <M>) < data.txt` also works (without having to know the number of lines in the "middle"). Unfortunately the last `M` lines are missing, so I had to do it as a separate line in the script. Perhaps if you know how to pipeline it (as I may be wrong) it would be perfect :) But this works too!

Comment: Using `tail` won't work, because it has to read the full input in to figure out how many lines from the end to use... so in that case the final `tail -n <M>` gets nothing on `stdin`, because the previous `tail -n +<N+1>` has taken it all!